# Using resources independent of file location

Tags: java, url, jar, classloader, embedded-resource

Here is my directory structure
XYZProject

- build
- dist
- nbproject
- src

I am working on netbeans.
Now I have a file called ABC.txt
I want to pack this in the jar file.
Now I did the following : made a new folder called Resources under source packages and put the file ABC.txt in that.

XYZProject

```
-- src  
  |
  -- Resources  
     |
     -- ABC.txt
```

Now I want to access this file independent of the file location. So I followed some tutorials and did this,

```
URL url = XYZProject.class.getClassLoader().getResource("Resources/ABC.txt");
String urlStr = urlStr.getFile().replaceAll("%20", " ");
System.out.println(urlStr);
BufferedReader reader;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(urlStr)); .....
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {...}
```

Now this works when I am running the code through netbeans i.e F6 and tada WORKS!!!
But when try to run the jar, it cannot locate the file. It throws FileNotFoundException
How do I access a text file inside a jar running it via netbeans and via java -jar ?
Also I have no idea why there's a %20 instead of space in the url that I get.

Output running VIA NB

```
/D:/.../.../.../.../XYZProject/build/classes/Resources/ABC.txt
```

Output running VIA java -jar

```
file:/D:/.../.../.../.../XYZProject/dist/XYZProject.jar!/Resources/ABC.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resource in a Jar is **not a `File`**.  It must be accessed by `URL` or `InputStream`.

I would probably use `URL` -> `InputStream` -> `InputStreamReader` -> `BufferedReader` (from memory, not tested).

Comment: So in this instance how would I be accessing the txt file inside the jar ?

Comment: reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream())); This worked out. Thanks

Comment: Is it the same for images ? Like images for icon etc, you access them as an input stream ?